# OnTouchListener performance - Android

Tags: android, performance, ontouchlistener

I wonder how much resource (cpu/memory usage) the OnTouchListener uses, when not in use, when im not clicking the button.

I ask this because im in a critical performance situation and Id like to add a secondary feature in my app with onrelease on a button that require the listener.

I wish there were the onrelease  in the layout just like onclick.

Comment: Could you perhaps state your question clearly, as it currently looks like an inner dialog rather then a  question.

Comment: U can get the question in 2 easy step; on the first sentence: step 1 remove "i wonder". step 2 add a question mark ("?") at the end of the sentence, easy!

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if there was a drastic change in your resource usage.
The simplest way of testing would be to run your app without `onTouch` and note down the cpu/memory usage. Then, enable your `onTouch` and see your cpu/memory usage. It's up to you to decide whether the usage is acceptable or not.

Comment: Have you run the tests?

Comment: cos the app is hungry :) what do you mean with tests?

Comment: Did you test the effect of onTouch using the method I proposed?